# WCF service slow after host renamed

Tags: wcf, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, net.tcp

Windows Server 2012 R2 / IIS 8.5 / net.tcp

Trying to replace 2008 R2 in my environment by setting up 2012 R2 servers and copying app folder to new server, create IIS site and create each WCF app under the site. Once ready, test and replace server by renaming hosts.

The WCF time for a single function goes from ~2 seconds to load to ~10 seconds or more after only renaming the host.

Using localsystem for each pool being used. Renaming the 2008 R2 server doesn't show to be effected by a rename. I tried other built-in users with no change.

IIS console shows correct hostname, searched registry for any cached (lsa has cached value that shows correct hostname).

I have 30+ 2012 R2 servers running the same, only difference is they were not renamed after setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase worker process for the designated application pool. Following is an example for your DefaultAppPool. But you might need to change it for your own app pool which isolate your wcf service.

[image]

Comment: Everything works fine until the host is renamed. Same config across all existing servers.